# Confused about Ruby length property

Tags: ruby, string

Why is the my `foo()` function printing out the string "YAAR" as having a length of 5?

```
def foo() 
map = Hash.new
File.open('dictionary.txt').each_line{ |s|
    word = s.split(',')
    if word.any? { |b| b.include?('AA') }
        puts word.last
        puts word.last.length
    end
    }
end
```

someFile.txt

```
265651,YAAR
265654,YAARS
```

**output**

```
YAAR
5
YAARS
6
```

Comment: The length is not lying. Try `puts ">" + word.last.inspect + "<"` and see what appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a newline '\n' at the end of both strings.  So, your split is receiving:

```
"265651,YAAR\n"
"265654","YAARS\n"
```

Comment: They are both one longer than expected - but doesn't this get removed with each_line?

Comment: @pst: [Apparently not!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-each_line) Strange.

Comment: @minitech Been out of everyday Ruby *way* too long. I would expect there to be a blank like in the `puts` output too, then ..?

Comment: fco explains it better above.  Lines read in from IO come with trailing newlines.  Chomp is the handiest remedy.

Answer (score 3):

reading from a file you'll get a new line char (\n) at the end of all the lines (except maybe the last one)

instead of

```
word = s.split(',')
```

in your loop, use this

```
word = s.split(',').map { |s| s.chomp }
```